# Having trouble installing mpi4py with Intel MPI

Tags: pip, package, mpi, mpi4py, intel-mpi

The title says it all. I have Intel MPI installed on my AWS instance and have sourced it to activate, and `which mpiexec` works and tells me its the Intel MPI. I don't have any other MPI installed right now. `$MPICC` is set as well.

Running

```
pip install mpi mpi4py --no-cache-dir
```

leads to the following error (this is the last paragraph, see also [full error message](https://pastebin.com/9MafnPH0)):

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/IQS/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1k4oxnqu/mpi4py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1k4oxnqu/mpi4py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-dj568ctj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/IQS/include/python3.8/mpi4py Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: As reported by the error message, did you *Check the logs for full command output* ?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I had linked the wrong mpicc, the one from source and not compiled. I realized this when I did `which mpicc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I had linked the wrong mpicc, the one from source and not compiled. I realized this when I did 'which mpicc'.